# Replace number by sum of other numbers in a list without subtraction

Tags: arrays, algorithm, language-agnostic, puzzle

I was asked:

Replace each number in a list by sum of remaining elements, the list is not sorted.
So suppose if we have a list of numbers like `{2, 7, 1, 3, 8}`, now we are to replace each element with sum of rest of elements. The output should be:

```
    {(7 + 1 + 3 + 8), (2 + 1 + 3 + 8), (2 + 7 + 3 + 8), (2 + 7 + 1 + 8), (2 + 7 + 1 + 3)}
==  {19, 14, 20, 18, 13}
```

I answered an obvious solution:
First evaluate `sum` of all numbers then subtract each element from `sum`. 
So for above list `sum` is `2 + 7 + 1 + 3 + 8` = `21`, then for output do like:

```
    {sum - 2, sum - 7, sum - 1, sum - 3, sum - 8}
    {21 - 2, 21 - 7, 21 - 1, 21 - 3, 21 - 8}
==  {19, 14, 20, 18, 13}
```

It needs only two iterations of list.

Then Interviewer asked me: Now do it without subtraction? and I couldn't answer :(

Is other solution possible? Can some share any other trick? A better trick is possible?

Lets extra memory space can be used (I asked after a few minutes of try, even then I couldn't answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility would be to compute prefix and suffix sums of your array and then combine the appropriate entries.  This would still be O(n) but needs more memory space so I think your original method is better.

In other words, from {2, 7, 1, 3, 8} compute {2, 2+7, 2+7+1, 2+7+1+3, 2+7+1+3+8} and {2+7+1+3+8, 7+1+3+8, 1+3+8, 3+8, 8} and then add the appropriate entries.

Comment: Right idea, wrong answer.  You need to exclude the element, i.e. the first array would be {0, 2, 9, 10, 13}.  Then just add the elements at each position together.

Comment: I agree, your way looks more elegant.

Comment: *`then add the appropriate entries`* You means in your two lists say A1, A2 for output I should add `output[i] = A1[i] + A2[N-i]` ? please solve further. Give me some more time...

Comment: You'll have two arrays, one increasing the other decreasing: So the first is {0, 2, 7+2 ...} and the other is {..., 3+8, 8, 0}.  Then you just have to add the two elements together at each position to get the sum.

Comment: In my scheme, output[i]=A1[i-1] + A2[i+1] if 0<i<N-1 or A2[1] if i==0 or A1[N-2] if i==N-1.  Joel's scheme is better as the formula becomes simply output[i]=A1[i]+A2[i].

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz Ok let me think...your answer is very helpful but I want to wait more..

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to sum everything *but* the element.  Then you don't have to subtract after the fact.  You just skip adding the element at the current index.

Alternatively, you could get a subset of the list that excludes the element at the current index, then just sum the subset together.  Pretty much the same thing as my first suggestion with more implementation detail.

Comment: I told him this, but I feel this is question not an answer (its too slow).

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan why not?

Comment: This ends up being `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @Teepeemm is that forbidden?

Comment: I suppose not, but given that OP and @Peter de Rivaz gave two different `O(n)` solutions, I don't think this is what the interviewer was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think anything better than yours.

But how about this :

Create a `(n-1)xn` matrix:

```
[ 2, 7, 1, 3, 8 ]

| 7, 1, 3, 8, 2 |  rotate by 1
| 1, 3, 8, 2, 7 |         by 2
| 3, 8, 2, 7, 1 |         by 3
| 8, 2, 7, 1, 3 |         by 4
```

Then Sum up the columns

C++'s `std::rotate_copy` can be used to create matrix

```
  std::vector<int> v1 {2, 7, 1, 3, 8 };
  std::vector<int> v2 (v1.size());
  int i,j;

  std::vector< std::vector<int> > mat;  
  for (int i=1; i<v1.size();++i){
     std::rotate_copy(v1.begin(),v1.begin()+i,v1.end(),v2.begin());
     mat.push_back(v2);
    }                                            

  for(j=0;j<v1.size();++j)  
    for(i=0;i<v1.size()-2;++i)
       v2[j]+=mat[i][j];

 for(i=0;i<v2.size();++i)
  std::cout<<v2[i]<<" ";
```

Comment: POW this is sum of other element that is I think question (not an answer) memory + iteration both need more :(

Comment: If time and space complexity don't matter, this does qualify the constraint of no subtraction.

Answer (score 1):

C++ implementation. O(n) and done by keeping sums of all elements before and after a certain index.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int a[] = {2,7,1,3,8};

    int prefix[5]; // Sum of all values before current index
    int suffix[5]; // Sum of all values after current index

    prefix[0] = 0; 
    suffix[4] = 0; 

    for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        prefix[i] = prefix[i-1] + a[i-1];
        suffix[4 - i] = suffix[4 - i + 1] + a[4 - i + 1]; 
    }   

    // Print result
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::cout << prefix[i] + suffix[i] << " ";
    }   
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[] = {2,7,1,3,8};

    int sum[5]={0};


     for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
       for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        sum[j]=sum[j]+a[(j+i+5)%5];
        }
      printf("%d ", sum[j]);  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of subtracting the element you can add the element multiplied by -1. Multiplication and addition are allowed operations, I guess.

Comment: Why should this be a wrong answer? `sum - a` and `sum + (-1*a)` give the same result, but without using subtraction.

Comment: @phlogratos Naa Phlogratos there **must be** some other solution, I have been think about every operator. For example read other answers. I am trying to understand...

Comment: I'm pretty sure the interviewer would have called that cheating.  At least I did when I asked this question.

Comment: Why is this cheating? Let's imagine you have to solve this in hardware and you have no subtraction chip, but a multiplier and an adder. In this case you can solve your problem.